# Spring Integration: mock testing jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration

Using Spring Integration, is there a way to to mock the result set that a `jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter` retrieves when unit testing? If not, what would be the recommended testing strategy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Anyway the `ResultSet` to return is a responsibility of `JdbcOperations`, not `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter`.

So, just mock `JdbcOperations#query` method and inject it into `<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>`

**UPDATE**

I mean this:

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter jdbc-operations="jdbcTemplate"/>
```

Where the `jdbcTemplate` bean is your custom implementation with mocked `query(String sql, ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)` method.

Comment: Artem, could you give a code snippet showing how to do this. When running in debug, <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter> shows as class type SourcePollingChannelAdapter - do not see any way to set the JdbcOperations on it. Even for JdbcPollingChannelAdapter - which is the class type I expected to see - JdbcOperations can only be set in the constructer, so how would one inject a mocked JdbcOperations into the <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter> instance which has been already instantiated by Spring and autowired into the test?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives would be to use an [embedded database](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-embedded-database-support) in your test cases or, probably easiest, is to simply send test data to the channel adapter's channel.

This technique is used in the [testing samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/testing-examples).